# How to read from XML that has same node names in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML document that looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teryt>
<catalog name="TERC" type="all" date="2015-01-01">
<row>
<col name="WOJ">02</col>
<col name="POW"/>
<col name="GMI"/>
<col name="RODZ"/>
<col name="NAZWA">DOLNOŚLĄSKIE</col>
<col name="NAZDOD">województwo</col>
<col name="STAN_NA">2015-01-01</col>
</row>
...
</row>
</catalog>
</teryt>
```

I have a code that works, but reads only the first **col** of every **row**:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument rssDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            rssDocument.Load("TERC.xml");

            System.Xml.XmlNodeList rssItems = rssDocument.SelectNodes("teryt/catalog/row");

            for (int i = 0; i < rssItems.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Xml.XmlNode rssNode;

                rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("col");

                if (rssNode != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rssNode.InnerText);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
```

What do I have to do, if I want to read `InnerText` from every **col** in all **rows** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
rssNode = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("col");
```

TO

```
XmlNodeList list = rssItems.Item(i).SelectNodes("col");

foreach(XmlNode node in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node .InnerText);
}
```

The name of the method explain what is doing: `SelectSingleNode`. Selects a single node with this name. You need to select all nodes using `SelectNodes` method

Comment: So that's how it works. Thanks a lot for you answer. I have 1 more question. Can I choose which "name=" I want to read ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var row in rssDocument.SelectNodes("teryt/catalog/row"))
{    
    foreach (var col in row.SelectNodes("col"))
    {             
        Console.WriteLine(col.InnerText);    
    }
}
```

I didn't test this. This is to give you an idea of the solution. You are only selecting one col from every row because SelectNodes("col") does not give you the nodes inside "col". It gives you the nodes named "col".